# mocha, how to handle test cases duplicate code?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js

as you can see, my test case have duplicate part.

How can I handle this? Just write a common function to reuse?

Is there a way of `mocha` to handle this?

```
 it('test case 1', function() {
    var target = {
        a: 1,
        b: 1
    };
    var source = {
        c: 1
    };
    expect(deepMerge(target, source)).to.deep.equal({a: 1, b: 1, c: 1});

    //dulplicate
    expect(target).to.eql(target);
    expect(source).to.eql(source);
});

it('test case 2', function() {
    var target = {
        a: 1,
        b: 1
    };
    var source = {
        a: 2,
        c: 1
    };

    expect(deepMerge(target, source)).to.deep.equal({a: 2, b: 1, c: 1});
    //dulplicate
    expect(target).to.eql(target);
    expect(source).to.eql(source);
});
//more test cases also have the duplicate part.
```

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17144197/running-the-same-mocha-test-multiple-times-with-different-data

Answer (score 0):

you can place all the duplicate expect cases in some function and call that function in every `it` block;

```js
function duplicateTests(target, source) {
    expect(target).to.eql(target);
    expect(source).to.eql(source);
}; 

it('test case 1', function() {
    var target = {
        a: 1,
        b: 1
    };
    var source = {
        c: 1
    };
    expect(deepMerge(target, source)).to.deep.equal({a: 1, b: 1, c: 1});

  duplicateTests(target, source);
});

it('test case 2', function() {
    var target = {
        a: 1,
        b: 1
    };
    var source = {
        a: 2,
        c: 1
    };

    expect(deepMerge(target, source)).to.deep.equal({a: 2, b: 1, c: 1});
    duplicateTests(target, source);
});
//more test cases also have the duplicate part.
```

Comment: Thanks for anwser. I know it can work.I just want to know is there a `mocha` way to do this? Maybe provide some `hook` like `beforeEach`?